# Cannot parse string to a Notification Activity

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I have an ExternalReceiver class, which receives notifications from the service:

```
public class ExternalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent!=null){
                MessageReceivingService.saveToLog(intent, context);            
        }
    }
}
```

The called saveToLog method stores the notification message:

```
protected static void saveToLog(Intent intent, Context context)
 {

    String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent exintent = new Intent (context, NotificationActivity.class);     
    intent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", newMessage);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, exintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Besked fra Salon")
            .setContentText(newMessage)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .getNotification();


    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.notification_number, notification);              
 }
```

It works fine so far since my phone displays the notification with the message. But when I'm clicking on the notification, it enters the NotificationAcivity class:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {
TextView textViewAc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

    textViewAc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAc);
            findViewById(R.id.textViewr1n1);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());               
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("NotificationMessage"))
        {
            // extract the extra-data in the Notification
            String msg = extras.getString("NotificationMessage");
            textViewAc.setText(msg);    
        }
    }


  }
}
```

the "extras" value from the intent is null, so the "newMessage" String is not actually stored. Why is the value not stored in this case ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you set `exintent` to `NotificationActivity` and adding putextra to `intent`,so Change

```
  intent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", newMessage);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

to

```
  exintent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", newMessage);
  exintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```